# Error can't set headers after they are sent. (res.send())

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am struggle with a error, and I would like a help if it is possible. I need to send an array from my Router: pronunciation / route: /words to a javaScript file which sent to that route ("/words") a array with words like (ask).

So in that route("/words") I am requesting to a API the word (ask), then I can grab all its values from the database.

Then I send an array back to the file where everything started by "return res.send(array)". All right is does work. But my problem starts when a have two words in that array which is sent to the router/route, even though the request works well and I am able to grab information of those words for example (ask, a) from the API, when it runs the line "return res.send(array)" I have a message error saying "Error can't set headers after they are sent."

Is that explained good enough to be understood?

Thanks in advance!

```
router.get("/words", function(req, res) {
    var wordsToBeSearched = req.query.str;
    var dictionary = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < wordsToBeSearched.length; i++) {
        var url = "http://www.dictionaryfake.com/api/xml/" + wordsToBeSearched[i];
        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                parseString(body, function (err, result) {
                    var word = (JSON.stringify(result["entry_list"]["entry"][0]["ew"][0]));
                    var sound = (JSON.stringify(result["entry_list"]["entry"][0]["sound"][0]["wav"][0]));
                    var symbol = (JSON.stringify(result["entry_list"]["entry"][0]["pr"][0]));
                    var singleWord = {word: word.replace(/"/g,''), symbol: symbol.replace(/"/g,''), sound: sound.replace(/"/g,'')};
                    dictionary.push(singleWord);

                    if(i === wordsToBeSearched.length) {
                        return res.send(dictionary);
                    };
                };
             };
         };
    };
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THbWn.png)

Comment: We have to see the relevant portions of your code to help you with this error.  This type of error is usually a mistake in how you handle asynchronous requests, but to advise you on exactly what you need to fix, we need to see your actual code.  Since you are new here, ***questions about code MUST include the relevant code***.  We are about 100x more effective here on stackoverflow in answering specific questions that show the actual code being used than we are at answering theoretical questions that could have thousands of possible causes.

Comment: You had some code in a comment that was helpful, but badly formatted. Try editing your question and put the code in the question. The basic problem was that you were calling `res.send` from within a `for` loop, which meant it got called more than once.

Comment: And, please use the "edit" link below your question to add the code to your question and then properly format it.  Multi-line code in comments is generally not readable and the code should be in the question itself anyway.  Here's [how to format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on stack overflow.

Comment: @jfriend00 and  thanks for the advices, I wrote the code of the route, and yes I am using an asynchronous request, if you guys need that piece of code as well just let me know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to wait for all of your requests to finish and then return you dictionary.
This can be nicely done using (async) [promises](http://caniuse.com/#search=promises). You can execute multiple promises and wait for all of them to resolve before **res.send**ing the results.

```
router.get("/words", function(req, res) {
  var wordsToBeSearched = req.query.str;
  var dictionary = [];
  var requests = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < wordsToBeSearched.length; i++) {
    var req = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var url = "http://www.dictionaryfake.com/api/xml/" + wordsToBeSearched[i];

      request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error || !response.statusCode === 200) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          parseString(body, function (err, result) {
            var word = (JSON.stringify(result["entry_list"]["entry"][0]["ew"][0]));
            var sound = (JSON.stringify(result["entry_list"]["entry"][0]["sound"][0]["wav"][0]));
            var symbol = (JSON.stringify(result["entry_list"]["entry"][0]["pr"][0]));
            var singleWord = {word: word.replace(/"/g,''), symbol: symbol.replace(/"/g,''), sound: sound.replace(/"/g,'')};
            dictionary.push(singleWord);
            resolve();
          });
        }
      });
    });
    requests.push(req);
  }

  Promise.all(requests)
    .then(() => {
      res.send(dictionary);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

Comment: thank you very much, it's working properly now. Thanks to promises as well :)